# SalesForce DataTable

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lighting, salesforce-communities, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am new to Sales Force and I don't know how to continue, I have searched and searched but I have not been able to solve it myself.
I have created a data table with Ligthing and Aura Component, I'll explain what I want to do exactly: Two dataTable that show -> the first: the level 1 accounts. The second: the level 2 accounts.

With a button that when the selections are changed from one account to another.

Right now I can show all accounts but only that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please expand on your question?
I see that you tagged Salesforce Marketing Cloud, but I am unsure how or where that plugs into your question.  It would be really helpful to get more information on what you are trying to do.  Try including the code you have or the outcome you are looking for.